# How do you do picture in picture using flutter?

Tags: flutter

Is there any way to do picture in picture with a flutter app? Kind of like what YouTube does when you're watching a video and navigate to another app.

They talk about it here:
https://youtu.be/hBPd2q2dmXY

I searched for it and couldn't find any info about it

Answer (score 9):

what you are asking is not available in flutter, you have to implement it in native only.
i have made one application which made pip for android only.

for this first declare a channel in flutter main.dart
like:-

```
static const platform = const MethodChannel('flutter.rortega.com.channel');
```

then in button click write:-

```
 await platform.invokeMethod('showNativeView');
```

which call a method in mainActivity.java

in mainActivity.java write following code:

```
package com.kovafood;

import io.flutter.embedding.android.FlutterActivity;

import android.app.PictureInPictureParams;
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Point;
import android.os.Build;
import android.util.Rational;
import android.view.Display;
import android.view.ViewTreeObserver;
import android.view.WindowManager;
import androidx.multidex.MultiDex;
import io.flutter.embedding.engine.FlutterEngine;
import io.flutter.plugin.common.MethodChannel;
import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
public class MainActivity extends FlutterActivity {
    private static final String CHANNEL = "flutter.rortega.com.channel";

    @Override
    public void configureFlutterEngine(@NonNull FlutterEngine flutterEngine) {
        super.configureFlutterEngine(flutterEngine);
        new MethodChannel(flutterEngine.getDartExecutor().getBinaryMessenger(), CHANNEL)
                .setMethodCallHandler(
                        (call, result) -> {
                            if (call.method.equals("showNativeView")){
                                Display d = getWindowManager()
                                        .getDefaultDisplay();
                                Point p = new Point();
                                if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB_MR2) {
                                    d.getSize(p);
                                }
                                int width = p.x;
                                int height = p.y;
                                Rational ratio
                                        = null;
                                if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
                                    ratio = new Rational(width, height);
                                }
                                PictureInPictureParams.Builder
                                        pip_Builder
                                        = null;
                                if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
                                    pip_Builder = new PictureInPictureParams.Builder();
                                }
                                if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
                                    pip_Builder.setAspectRatio(ratio).build();
                                }
                                if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
                                    enterPictureInPictureMode(pip_Builder.build());
                                }
                            } else {
                                result.notImplemented();
                            }
                        }
                );
    }
}
```

in androidManifest.xml,between the first activity add

```
android:supportsPictureInPicture="true"
```

Comment: How to show a spesific widget instead of whole screen to picture in picture mode ?

Comment: for that reason you have to make one bool variable , so once user press home button on device that time that will be true and according to that variable show a particular widget on screen.

Comment: @MohitModh, It is working good, just two things how can I trigger method when app goes in background or back button pressed, in Kotlin we can use onUserLeaveHint but could't have found any thing similar in flutter also need two callback when PIP mode swtiched like in kotlin we use onPictureInPictureModeChanged.  do you know how to achieve these two things in flutter? Thanks

Answer (score 6):

The feature is called "PiP mode" which should be a lot easier to google than "picture in picture". 
There is a flutter package but I have not tried it (also appears to be android only unfortunately)  https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/flutter_android_pip

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'dart:async';

import 'package:flutter/services.dart';
import 'package:flutter_android_pip/flutter_android_pip.dart';

void main() => runApp(new MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyAppState createState() => new _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  String _platformVersion = 'Unknown';

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    //  initPlatformState();
  }
/*
  // Platform messages are asynchronous, so we initialize in an async method.
  Future<void> initPlatformState() async {
    String platformVersion;
    // Platform messages may fail, so we use a try/catch PlatformException.
    try {
      platformVersion = await FlutterAndroidPip.platformVersion;
    } on PlatformException {
      platformVersion = 'Failed to get platform version.';
    }

    // If the widget was removed from the tree while the asynchronous platform
    // message was in flight, we want to discard the reply rather than calling
    // setState to update our non-existent appearance.
    if (!mounted) return;

    setState(() {
      _platformVersion = platformVersion;
    });
  }*/

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new MaterialApp(
      home: new Scaffold(
        appBar: new AppBar(
          title: const Text('Plugin example app'),
        ),
        body: new Center(
          child: new RaisedButton(
            child: new Text("press"),
            onPressed: () {
              FlutterAndroidPip.enterPictureInPictureMode;
            },
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```