# How to create a background floating widget ? - Flutter / Dart

Tags: flutter, dart, package, system-alert-window

Is it possible to create a widget that floats in the background ( i.e have a floating app when the user presses the home button)?

I tried using the system_alert_window ( https://pub.dev/packages/system_alert_window), however, it only allows text and button to float in the background, no other flutter widget could have been floated.

The images shown below are what I'm trying to achieve here[image]

[image]

Comment: What you are looking for is 'Picture In Picture' (PIP).

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54763337/how-do-you-do-picture-in-picture-using-flutter/54764010

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do you do picture in picture using flutter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54763337/how-do-you-do-picture-in-picture-using-flutter)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AFAIK, there is an available package of exactly what you needed. I suggest to explore [pip_view](https://pub.dev/packages/pip_view) plugin. [Here](https://pub.dev/packages/pip_view/example) is an example that was provided in the page:

[image]